# Json parsing:Service handling Exception in Android

Tags: android, json, service, android-asynctask

I have been feching datas from url.Depending on first url,second will works and depending on the second third will work.I have been set all datas into spinner when i  modify the first spinner the other two spinner modifies and shows an error.

```
03-28 11:17:38.958: D/dalvikvm(659): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8320 objects / 625048 bytes in 63ms
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 59: http://192.169.11.175/AndroidService/Restful.svc/getarea/80 Feet Road
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:970)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.testspinner.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:67)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.testspinner.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:33)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.testspinner.HomeActivity$GetArea.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:192)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.testspinner.HomeActivity$GetArea.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-28 11:17:38.958: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  ... 4 more
```

**HomeActivity.class**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    private static String state_url = "/AndroidService/restful.svc/GetState/";
    private static String city_url = "/AndroidService/restful.svc/Getcity/";
    private static String city_area = "/AndroidService/Restful.svc/getarea/";
    Spinner sp_state,sp_city,sp_area,sp_pin;
    ArrayList<String> state_name,state_id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        sp_state = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_state);
        sp_area = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_area);
        sp_city = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_city);
        sp_pin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_pin);

        new GetState(HomeActivity.this).execute();
        sp_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) 
            {
                String item = sp_state.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(!item.equals("select"))
                {
                    new GetCity(HomeActivity.this, state_id.get(pos)).execute();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        sp_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = sp_city.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                if(!name.equals("select"))
                {
                new GetArea(HomeActivity.this, name).execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }



    class GetState extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Context con;    
        public GetState(Context c) 
        {
            this.con = c;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(state_url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            if(jsonStr!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    state_name = new ArrayList<String>();
                    state_id = new ArrayList<String>();
                    state_name.add("select");
                    state_id.add("select");
                    JSONArray ary = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for(int i=0;i<ary.length();i++)
                    {
                        String name = ary.getJSONObject(i).getString("StateName");
                        int city_id = ary.getJSONObject(i).getInt("PkId");
                        state_name.add(name);
                        state_id.add(""+city_id);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ArrayAdapter<String> state_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.textView_custom, state_name);
            sp_state.setAdapter(state_Adapter);
        }

    }


    class GetCity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Context con;
        String state_id;
        ArrayList<String> mycity;
        public GetCity(Context c,String id) {
            this.con = c;
            this.state_id = id;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(city_url+""+state_id, ServiceHandler.GET);

            if(jsonStr!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONArray myary = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    mycity = new ArrayList<String>();
                    mycity.add("select");
                    for(int i=0;i<myary.length();i++)
                    {

                        String city = myary.getJSONObject(i).getString("City");
                        mycity.add(city);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ArrayAdapter<String> state_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.textView_custom, mycity);
            sp_city.setAdapter(state_Adapter);
        }

    }

    class GetArea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Context con;
        String name;
        ArrayList<String> myarea;
        public GetArea(Context c,String name) {
            this.con = c;
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(city_area+""+name, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("CityResponse: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if(jsonStr!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONArray myary = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    myarea = new ArrayList<String>();
                    myarea.add("select");
                    for(int i=0;i<myary.length();i++)
                    {

                        String city = myary.getJSONObject(i).getString("Area");
                        Log.d("city", city);

                        myarea.add(city);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ArrayAdapter<String> state_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.textView_custom, myarea);
            sp_area.setAdapter(state_Adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

**ServiceHandler.class**

```
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

Comment: it shows some illegal character in your link.i think its due to **SPACES** in your link.

Comment: which link is no working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

You can see your url from logcat like this

`/AndroidService/Restful.svc/getarea/80 Feet Road`

from that you can see **80 Feet Road** there is space between them

space need to replace with `%20` use below method to use your url **[URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)**

You can use the `java.net.URLEncoder` to **encode** the **URL** as in

`import java.net.URLEncoder;`

```
String uu;
try {
        uu = URLEncoder.encode(yoururl,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```